# Where is the type of the object passed to an SharpSNMP async callback specified?

Tags: c#, snmp, sharp-snmp

I'm using SharpSNMP (8.5, the latest version from NuGet) asynchronously to poll a device. It's pretty easy and working apparently fine but there's one thing I can't figure out even from looking at the source code for SharpSnmpLib: Where the type of the object supplied to the callback method is specified.

For example:

Here I crate a new **SNMP GET** request and call **BeginGetResponse**.

```
var message = new GetRequestMessage(RequestCounter.NextId, VersionCode.V2, community, oids);
var udpSocket = SNMPAddress.GetSocket();

// pass my GetRequestMessage as the state object
var v = message.BeginGetResponse(SNMPAddress, new UserRegistry(), udpSocket, new AsyncCallback(HandlePollCompletion), message);
```

The method **message.BeginGetResponse** is defined in the **SnmpMessageExtension** class and ultimately calls **BeginReceive** on the socket (following snippet is from the [SharpSNMP code](https://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SharpSnmpLib/Messaging/SnmpMessageExtension.cs)):

```
public static IAsyncResult BeginGetResponse(this ISnmpMessage request, IPEndPoint receiver, UserRegistry registry, Socket udpSocket, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{

    // ** code snipped from example for readability **

    var ar = udpSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, callback, state);
    return new SnmpMessageAsyncResult(ar, udpSocket, registry, receiver, buffer);
}
```

This returns a **SnmpMessageAsyncResult** object but this is never passed to the call to **udpSocket.BeginReceive** so I can't see how it then can later turn up passed to the callback method.

When the reply comes in, my handler method **HandlePollCompletion** is called:

```
private void HandlePollCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // grab handle to original message
    GetRequestMessage message = (GetRequestMessage)ar.AsyncState;

    // end the async call
    try 
    {
        var response = message.EndGetResponse(ar);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {}

    // process reply here
}
```

If I put a breakpoint in, I can see the object **ar** that is passed to **HandlePollCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)** has the type **SnmpMessageAsyncResult**.

But as far as I can see, **HandlePollResult(IAsyncResult ar)** is called by the socket i.e. not from within SharpSNMP.

So by what mechanism is the object passed to **HandlePollCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)** a **SnmpMessageAsyncResult**? Perhaps I don't understand the async model as well as I thought I did..

Thanks for your insight,
Giles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't need to care much about that.

Begin/End pair is now obsolete and you should use the Async method with async/await.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I was just intrigued. Regarding the Async methods, I see they're in Github but apparently not in the latest version on NuGet; Are you planning an updated release soon or should I pull the latest code from Github and compile the DLL(s) myself?

Comment: @Gilesatwork the master branch should be marked as 9.0 RC soon. Yes, a new release is coming pretty soon.

Comment: @Gilesatwork 9.0 RC1 is here, https://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/releases/view/116908 RTM will be soon published.

Comment: Thanks - grabbed the RC and am having a play now. Most appreciated.

Comment: @Gilesatwork I have published the final build today, but one critical issue about async support was found a few days ago. It would lead to high memory fragmentation, so I am afraid would be a road blocker for you. Will try to address that in 9.1 or 9.5 In a few weeks (with big design changes).